# How to clean up secondary index?

Tags: indexing, cassandra

In my traffic, the life cycle of the data in Cassandra is short, normally one day, then it will be deleted.

So during the middle night, the maintenance task will flush and compact all key space, the purpose is to free disk usage.

But I found the secondary index sstable is not deleted or compacted.

So do I need specific command to release these index data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to compact the (private) CF containing the 2I information separately.  Not sure off the top of my head if you can do this from nodetool, but you can definitely do it from JMX (org.apache.cassandra.db.IndexColumnFamilies).

Comment: Yes, your correct, I use JMX to change the setcompactionthreshold, and then compact the secondary index. It works for me. And when have very unbalance traffic and frequently change data, it will be useful to compact index in time.